# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I have this test method using XUnit in .NET Core 3.1. When I run it locally, it passed.

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task RemoveCampaign_RemoveOneCampaignIsSuccessWhenCampaignIdIsValid()
    {
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/Campaign/find?title=Test");
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CampaignResponseDto>>(responseString).FirstOrDefault();
        Assert.IsType<CampaignResponseDto>(result);

        if (result != null)
        {
            var deleteResponse = await client.DeleteAsync(string.Format("/api/Campaign/{0}", result.Id));

            // Assert
            Assert.True(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, deleteResponse.StatusCode);
        }
    }
```

But when I run it at Azure DevOps in ASP.NET Core, it failed with this error message:

```
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Cannot deserialize the
> current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[xxx.Api.DTO.CampaignResponseDto]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'type', line 1, position 8.
```

Added:

```
public class CampaignResponseDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

and responseString (in local)

```
{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}
```

Comment: please share the response string and structure of CampaignResponseDto

Comment: @AmitVerma I added CampaignResponseDto and responseString

Comment: Looks like the JSON you are receiving in the response does not represent a list. it is representing only a single object. You might want to change to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CampaignResponseDto>`

Comment: your response string doesn't contain any json related to your dto. there must be some data related to your dto.